# how to Pass custom field value to post query array category field

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to make doctors_category section dynamically. Pls take a look my query. i created a custom field for write category name. And when i write a category name then show those category post on page.

```
<?php $doctors_list = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type'=>'doctor',
  'posts_per_page'=> -1,
  'order'=>'ASC',
  'doctors_category'=> $doctor_cat
  ));
  $unique = "_doctor_";
  $doctor_cat= get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'depertment_cat',true);
?>
```

I tried this query but didn't work.So please someone help me.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  Try this,
  <?php 
   $doctor_cat= get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'depertment_cat',true);

   $doctors_list = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type'=>'doctor',
  'posts_per_page'=> -1,
  'order'=>'ASC',
  'category'=> $doctor_cat
   ));

   ?>
```